# combine datasource values asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, iqueryable

I am trying to see if their is any possible way to combine data source values. The structure of the data would be the same,

```
Year| Amount Used| Amount Collected | Amount Saved
```

What I want do do it combine data sources that are `IQueryable<T>` data types **T being the same type** that would be this structure and then bind it to a gridview.

Only column I dont want to add together is the year, because I want the sources to combine based on the year, and also every year may not be in the data sources.

How is this possible, would the only way is making a foreach statement for each source and combine them manually?

I'm looking for something simplier

Comment: please take a look at my answer, you will need to `Merge` the data.

Comment: Please clarify this: `data sources that are IQueryable<T> data types T being the same type that would be this structure`

Comment: meaning that both data sources are IQueryable<cars> or both are IQueryable<computers> thats why I left it as T cause cars would have a different structure than computers. but for example I am trying to combine two cars mileage, for example if car1 in 2006 drove 2000 miles and car2 in 2006 drove 9 miles, i would want the result to be 2006 2009 miles, the reason I wouldnt want a foreach loop is because its way more than just one column I want to combine

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ's Union operator to combine the two IQueryable data types. I would create a new variable with the result of the union operation. From there group by year and use a aggregate function (sum would probably be what you are looking for) to perform the calculations.

EDIT: Here is an example. I will tell you I am in the process of learning LINQ myself and there are LOTS of tutorials out there (Google is your friend). I have been learning LINQ in VB which has a somewhat different syntax as C#. I did my best to write the example in C# but it may not be exactly correct but will give you a good starting point.

```
var unionResult = dataSet1.Union(dataSet2);

var groupedResult = from r in unionResult
        group r By r.Year into g
        Select new
        {
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            TotalUsed = g.Sum(r => r.AmountUsed),
            TotalCollected = g.Sum(r => r.AmountCollected),
            TotalSaved = g.Sum(r => r.AmountSaved
        };
```

If the you are using LINQ to DataSets the first line may need to be replaced with:

```
var unionResult = dataSet1.AsEnumerable().Union(dataSet2.AsEnumerable());
```

Here are some of the resources (other than Google) that I have been using. Scott Gu's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) (on the right click the LINQ tag). [4 Guys](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113652/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021109-1.aspx) has a good multipart series also.

Comment: could you give an example with syntax?

Comment: not sure if this method would work but I just ended up using a foreach statement to accomplish, the worse it could be is n^2, n being the number of records in the source and since n is never bigger than 30, their is no real damage